# Z and Z* have the same argument?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

I know that the answer is no because they are conjugates. But how can I express it with a demonstration?

Comment: What is the argument of $i$? What is the argument of $i^*$?

Comment: Given that $z = x + iy$, what is $z^*$ ? Do you know the formula for argument? Can you prove it now? Or attempt it for simpler complex numbers like $i$, $1+i$ etc. and see if it is likely to be correct.

Comment: Well that's the question: 'Given a complex number z, say whether the following statements are true and why'. Then I have to answer to ' Z and Z* have the same argument'? Z* is the conjugate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the definition and a little trigonometry you can work this out. First, clearly the claim is false if $\;z\in\Bbb R\;$ . Now, if

$$\;z=x+iy\implies  \overline z=x-iy\;,\;\;x,y\in\Bbb R,\;\text{and we can assume}\;x,y\neq0$$

to avoid the false case $\;z\in\Bbb R\;$ we saw above,  or the easy case $\;\arg z=\pm\frac\pi2\implies\arg\overline z=\mp\frac\pi2\;$ showing the arguments indeed are different , but then:
$$\arg z=\arctan\frac yx\neq-\arctan\frac yx=\arctan\frac{-y}x=\arg\overline z$$